# How can i get data in `handleOnDrop` function in react-papaparse?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how i get the data and put the data in some charts using papaparse.

I could get the data from `console.log` when I put a csv file into a box.

like this:

[image]

but I have no idea how to display data on the web.

so this is my code :

```js
import React from "react";
import { CSVReader } from "react-papaparse";
import styled from "styled-components";

const DataMenu = () => {
  const handleOnDrop = data => {
    <div>{data.slice(2, -1)}</div>;
  };

  const handleOnError = (err, file, inputElem, reason) => {
    console.log(err);
  };

  const handleOnRemoveFile = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <Menu>
      <CSVReader
        onDrop={handleOnDrop}
        onError={handleOnError}
        addRemoveButton
        onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
        style={{
          dropArea: {
            borderColor: "#467cf0",
            borderRadius: 20,
            width: 540,
            height: 300,
          },
        }}
      ></CSVReader>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default DataMenu;

const Menu = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(245, 243, 243, 0.575);
`;
```

So I've tried to put  `div` in the `handleOnDrop` to be able to display the data  but I don't know how to display it. and if it's possible, I'd like to put the data into some charts using `Chart.js` later.

Comment: Look into 'state' in React.JS and see how that works. You'll need to assign 'data' to a property on state so you can change it after load and your interface can update to reflect accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answering Sir! i will try to do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use "useState" to hold your data. For example,

```
 const [dataVariable, setDataVariable] = useState()

 const handleOnDrop = data => {
    data.forEach( apiData => {
          dataVariable = apiData.data
           Console.log(dataVariable)
     }) 
   };"
```

You can try this first.

Comment: that is not how you set state.

Comment: what can i do with that way ??

Comment: Well, that was an example. I trying to remember the corect way, but it almost the same as above. You create a state using the "useState" and then you either assign the variable or the set Variable to the api data. And only then, you can extract the api data using the "useEffect". The "useEffect" is the same way as you extract the api using "Fetch" in javascript